# VS Code Workspace, How to avoid pushing ".code-workspace" file to remote repository?

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control, push, workspace

I have cloned a remote repository from Azure DevOps to local laptop by VS Code.

Next, I saved the folder as a Workspace (File / Save Workspace As ..). Saving as Workspace added a new file with `..code-workspace` extension.

Now, when I open Version Control, I see that there is a change (adding .code-workspace file) to the local repository. However, I don't want to push this file to the remote repository.

Please let me know how to avoid it. When I right click on the change, I see the following options:

[image]

Comment: If its using git, add it to your .gitignore.  There is an option to do that in your screenshot

Comment: you can add a file in your `.git` folder to act as a local `.gitignore` if you don't want your teammates to know of this file, you have to search for the details

Comment: When I select "Add to .gitignore", a new change comes up which is adding ".gitignore" file. However, I don't want to commit this change to the remote repository.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid changing the repo project's `.gitignore` which comes up as a uncommited change, you can instead change you local repo's .git's folder's gitignore file.

> Patterns which are specific to a particular repository but which do not need to be shared with other related repositories (e.g., auxiliary files that live inside the repository but are specific to one user’s workflow) should go into the $GIT_DIR/info/exclude file.

Credit: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

This is in:

`$GIT_DIR/info/exclude`

Simply add the follow line (assuming `.vscode` in in your project root) to that `exclude text file`

`/.vscode/*.code-workspace`